Show that the set $ { ∧ , → } $ is not complete
how can i show that the set $ \{ \land , \rightarrow\} $ is not complete ?
i defined $ A = p \veebar q $ (with $\veebar$ for XOR) and tried to solve using structural but didn't know how to complete it .

Please define "complete".

How would you compose those to obtain $\neg$?

@NaïmFavier In this context, complete usually means that you can represent any Boolean function. Normally you reduce to ${\land,\lor,\neg}$, as this system is complete (well-known).
